# Error during the Installation of Magento 1.14

Tags: layout, blocks, install, ee-1.14

When installing the latest Magento EE version, I receive the following error

> Fatal Error: Call to member function append() on a non-object in /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php

http://f.cl.ly/items/2c0Z0e102O0r1O3D0B3H/magento-install-error.png

Is this a problem with EE, or is it a problem with this specific system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a problem with your specific system.  (The bugs Magento ships are more subtle)

If you take a look at the method definition around the line called out by the error handler

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->loadLayout('install_wizard');
    $step = $this->_getWizard()->getStepByRequest($this->getRequest());
    if ($step) {
        $step->setActive(true);
    }

    $leftBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('install/state', 'install.state');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($leftBlock);
    return $this;
}
```

You can see it's this line that triggers an error

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($leftBlock);
```

Magento's installer uses the same framework code to run as Magento itself.  What's happening in this specific case is the installer attempts to fetch the block named `left`, and call its `append` method.  However, there's no block named left so `getBlock` returns false.

The most likely cause of this problem is a missing installer layout update XML file.  The following file

```
app/design/install/default/default/layout/main.xml
```

is where the `left` block is defined for the installer.  The most common reason for this error will be this file missing, or this file modified.

Comment: Tracked it down with this info. In this project's repo, the entire "app/design/install" folder was removed so no installation process. Should work if you drop this and the corresponding skin folder into the project temporarily.